# How do I grep or sed in a continuous stream of characters?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep, buffer

#### I have a program that output some text and then a continuous stream of characters:

```
perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10'
```

I want to exit this program as soon as "A" is seen in the output and I  tried:

```
grep -m 1 A <(perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10')
```

However, it seems like grep doesn't see the "A"s until the perl program exits.

I also tried with sed with no luck;

```
sed /A/q <(perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10')
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that both `grep` and `sed` process their input linewise unless they are told otherwise. One workaround is to insert newlines, e.g. with coreutils `fold`:

```
grep -m 1 A \
  <(perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10' | fold -w1)
```

But this still has issues because of pipe-buffering. You can disable this with coreutils `stdbuf`:

```
grep -m 1 A \
  <(perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10' |
    stdbuf -o0 fold -w1)
```

Another alternative is to use `dd`, e.g.:

```
perl -E '$|=1;print "OUT\n";print "A" and sleep 1 for 1..10' |
while :; do
  c=$(dd bs=1 count=1 status=none)
  if [[ "$c" == "A" ]]; then
    break
  else
    : Do something else
  fi
done
```

Comment: nope, `grep(1)` and `sed(1)` read with a large buffer when input doesn't come from a terminal, so you cannot assume reading whole lines, but large chunks of data, which makes the problem worse.

Comment: @LuisColorado: When they are at the end of a pipe they use line buffering. Compare e.g.: `seq 3 | while read; do echo $REPLY; sleep 1; done | grep .` to `seq 3 | while read; do echo $REPLY; sleep 1; done | grep . | cat`

Comment: Nope, they process the input line by line, but they read in chunks dictated by the filesystem info (one full disk block each time).  Trust me, or look at the program sources.  The objective is to be efficient, no improvement comes out from reading line by line (that's indeed impossible in a pipe, as no character processing ---as in device driver--- is done at the kernel to get input at each end of line marker, so no line buffering is possible)

Comment: @LuisColorado: I see what you mean. My explanation is based on how it appears to the user without going into too much detail.  I  have made some adjustments based on your comments.